# How to get the objects from a request url module function to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, module, request

So, i was working in on multi API project where ,there's one part where one had to enter the address , for where you want to get the weather outputs, and i am stuck in a part where i can take the API values of long. and lat. converted out of a address string and pass it to a API for weather outputs.as i can't access the API output of one to another.
The request url is like this:

```js
request({url:url,json:true}, (error,response) => { 
   console.log(response.body.current.weather_descriptions[0] +' The temperature is '+chalk.inverse(response.body.current.temperature)+' but it feels like '+ chalk.inverse(response.body.current.feelslike))
})
```

Comment: Please read this: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Answer (score -1):

ok, i found an answer using call back function, i have answered below the code.

```js
const geoCode = (geoUrl, callback) => {
    request({url:geoUrl,json:true}, (error,response) => { 
        if(error)
        {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the server.....')
        }
        else{
    callback(undefined,{
        latitude:response.body.data[0].latitude,
        longitude:response.body.data[0].longitude
    })
}
        
        
        })
}

geoCode(geoUrl,(error,data) =>
{
    var url = 'youur api'
    url = url+data.latitude+","+data.longitude
// console.log(url)

    request({url:url,json:true}, (error,response) => { 
       
        if(error)
        {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the server.....')
        }
        else{
            console.log(response.body.current.weather_descriptions[0] +' The temperature is '+chalk.inverse(response.body.current.temperature)+' but it feels like '+ chalk.inverse(response.body.current.feelslike))
}
        
        
        })
})
```